# Server-side data submit in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new to meteor.Iam using meteor aldeed autoform and collection2 packages in my app.here is my client js file.

```
Schema = {};

Schema.dc_address = new SimpleSchema({

 'dataCenterName': {
    type: String,
    index: 1,
    label:'Name of the Provider',
    regEx: /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/
  },
'address1': {
    type: String,
    index: 1,
    label:'Address Line 1',
    regEx: /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/
  },
'address2': {
    type: String,
    index: 1,
    label:'Address Line 2',
    regEx: /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/
  },

});


  Template.dataCenters.helpers({//dataCenters is my main template
    steps: function() {
      return [{
        id: 'dc_address',
        title: 'Name & Address',
        template: 'dc_address',
        formId: 'dc_address_form',
        onSubmit: function(data, wizard) {



        var params=_.extend(wizard.mergedData(), data);
        alert(params);

     var jsonrpc = new $.JsonRpcClient({ ajaxUrl: 'http://172.16.4.190:8384' });


        jsonrpc.call(
                 'dataCenterCreate', params,
                     function(result) {alert('Pizzeria answered: ' + $.toJSON(result)); },
                    function(error)  { console.log('There was an error', $.toJSON(error)); }
            );

        }
      }];
    }
  });
```

here is my html page

```
<template name="dc_address">
<div class="form-wrapper">
  {{#autoForm doc=this.data id="dc_address_form"  schema=Schema.dc_address }}
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{> afQuickField name="dataCenterName" placeholder="Enter DataCenter Name"}}
    </div>  
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td class="col-md-6">
    {{> afQuickField name="address1" placeholder="#7 4th cross"}}
    </td>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <td class="col-md-6">   
    {{> afQuickField name="address2" placeholder="ITPL-banglore"}}
    </td>
    </tr>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md pull-right">Next</button>

  {{/autoForm}}
  </div>
</template>
```

That works pretty well although - it's CLIENT side submit  => it is not secure.
How do I implement it is in server side?

Comment: What do you mean by "not secure"? Anyone can send something? Have a look at either Meteor.call to make a call to the server, add validation there and then to your external RpcServer - or add Collections and secure them with Meteor.subscribe-rules.

Answer (score 0):

For security you should remove autopublish and insecure packages. Once you do this inserting anything into the databases will throw an error. Try Posts.insert({}) in the console to see the errors appear.

You get around this by adding allow and deny rules on your server (see the meteor docs for more on allow/deny rules). You can also use meteor methods using: Meteor.call(...) to insert docs into the database without having any allow rules set up. You'd have to do your own checks within the meteor method in this case.